# Can an MDM computer be taken over again?

Tags: apple-id, mdm, maintenance

We are provided with laptops (MacBooks) in our company, but the laptops are provided by default with MDM JAMF maintenance. It is possible to ask that to be removed, and sometimes requests such as that are granted. I am not sure mine will, but I am in the process.

I read about it, and I am trying to understand - would it be possible for the admins, once they let me remove MDM/etc. - to reinstall it again without my permission by sending some signal to the computer? Meaning, is there something persistent that cannot be changed once MDM is installed?

I understand they can force to be again by default on MDM if you choose to wipe the computer, but that's not my intention.

The reason I ask is that we are allowed to use the laptops for some personal information, and I would feel irked if I knew the company's admin can reinstall an MDM profile without my permission or physical access to the laptop - especially I would feel uncomfortable with logging in to my Apple ID (I don't have a "company" Apple ID).

Comment: If you consider personal use to be private, never mix personal and work use on the same computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is the Apple service that was initially called [Device Enrollment Program (DEP)](https://www.jamf.com/blog/apple-device-enrollment-program-apple-it-innovation/) and is now called Automated Enrollment.

The device can be “[taken over again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/377935/5472)” as that’s how the system is designed.

You can’t easily disable this, either since it’s an administrative record that Apple maintains. There are some guides to thwart it, but I’ve not seen a recently updated one.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204142

Apple doesn’t hide the fact when the MDM manage this enforced, but you would need to modify the firmware / activation process to get around it if your request is denied. If you manage to remove the MDM profile, you haven’t removed all the changes made by the MDM necessarily and if you erase the Mac, you’ll likely be prompted to re-enroll.

You could ask they retain the ability to manage the Mac, but remove you from active management. Then you could erase and use the machine privately and know if they decide to manage it again when you see the “enrollment approval” prompt.

The “should you mix private with work” discussion is highly personal. It’s really not worth it in my experience. Even bringing a work machine into your home network is sketchy if you’re not going to manage to separate the traffic and devices. Active MDM and surveillance and software that tries to monitor traffic for the workplace aren’t likely designed for subtle distinctions between a private home life and what one might expect/inspect/record in the workplace.

---

In the end, you have to trust them to a certain extent. If you feel they are honest in rescinding all "remote monitoring" then you might be safe. If you can't trust them, why risk it? Keep in mind, some parts of IT may be bound by NDA to never tell most staff what they do or just consider they work directly for the company and are there to investigate / snoop on people and not help them.

This conflict is something every professional IT team has to deal with and usually support / IT is mostly on your side and security / legal / HR isn't mostly on your side. YMMV and don't assume your team is anything like "most" or "some" since every country / region of country / industry / group is made up of individuals. There can be a bad egg in even the best batch of tech workers that you expect and observe to be regularly very transparent.

Comment: Thank you, @bmike. I have no intention to wipe the hard disk, since I don't think the admins would like it, especially if they set it up in such a way that it requires re-enrollment. I just want to know if, once THEY remove the MDM profile from my Mac, and the Mac is no longer being actively managed, if they can add the management, the backup services, etc. without having physical access to the laptop. If so, this is unacceptable, and I will just buy my own laptop.

Comment: They might be able to - it depends on their skill and what else the MDM did. I can't reasonably understand what they have in place once the MDM seal has been broken and they had the chance to install admin passwords, ssh keys, remote management, call home software, security software, etc... You have to wipe it to know you are "safe" and if you wipe it, you can then watch VERY CLOSELY on what they install. They could be totally hands off, they could have remote root access and total control. @appleUser

Comment: I'll edit my post, but we're really getting into opinion / over generalization - something to consider is your "threat model" - are you working for Apple where you know international spies try to gain employment / access / influence  or are you working for Bob's Insurance in sleepy rural town or Joe's Gun Rental in Palestine or Syria where the stakes are so much higher than most companies I've worked for.

Comment: thank you. this is very disappointing. I work for a company where the lines between "personal" and "work" are quite blurry, for a good reason. The thought of some admin in this big organization has random access to a device where I store personal information is not pleasant. I am not doing anything illicit or anything terribly embarrassing, but this is still not ok to have such access when the underlying understanding is that employees use their devices that way.

Comment: Yup @appleUser you have to trust every single person - with work-life balance, I strongly prefer to have a display with keyboard and mouse attached and shut the work Mac, unplug it, plug my personal iPad or Mac in and be on my device. Work gets enough of my time on their device, unplug from work and be yourself on your personal devices is my advice.