# Boot from external drive with no admin password or recovery mode?

Tags: macos, mdm, firmware-password

I recently left an organization that had placed a bunch of restrictions on my Macbook Air M2, which is running Sonoma 14.3.1. I don't have an admin password, and all startup options (recovery mode, safe mode) are locked. Most settings are locked by Jamf, a restrictions software - I can't change startup disk or access profiles, or I also can't contact them to get it removed.

Is there any way I can reinstall macOS to get rid of the restrictions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an MDM computer be taken over again?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/442941/can-an-mdm-computer-be-taken-over-again)

Comment: i'm trying to remove the restrictions, that person is afraid of their restrictions being restored. different issue

Comment: Apple may help if you have proof of ownership (purchase receipt with your name and your Mac's serial number). Otherwise it is the old work place.